# android startActivity undefined

Tags: android, start-activity

I am making a drawing app and would like to share the image. However, I meet an error for the `startActivity` part, of which the error writes `The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type` . What does it means and how could it be tackled? Many thanks in advances!!!

### EDIT:

posted further code settings for the codes: `ActivityA` Calling `shareImage()` in `PaintView`.

I am not sure whether the Context in this way is ok? Except this newly added sharing function, the code without sharing runs very smoothly.

### PaintView

```
// the main screen that is painted
public class PaintView extends View 
{      
   Context context_new;       
   private boolean isFileAlreadySaved = false;
   String savedFilePath = "";

   private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 10;
   // other declarations here

   // PaintView constructor initializes the PaintView
   public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
   {
      super(context, attrs); // pass context to View's constructor
      this.context_new=context;
      paintScreen = new Paint(); // used to display bitmap onto screen

      // set the initial display settings for the painted line
      paintLine = new Paint();
      paintLine.setAntiAlias(true); // smooth edges of drawn line
      paintLine.setColor(Color.BLACK); // default color is black
      paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // solid line
      paintLine.setStrokeWidth(5); // set the default line width
      paintLine.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // rounded line ends
      pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, Path>();
      previousPointMap = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();
   } // end DoodleView constructor


   public void shareImage()
   {
        Intent share;
        File attachment = null;

        if(isFileAlreadySaved == true)
        {
            attachment = new File(savedFilePath);
            boolean isFileThere = attachment.exists();
            if (isFileThere == true)
            {
                share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
                share.setType("image/png");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share drawing"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please save the image first...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        };
   };
```

### ActivityA:

```
   public OnClickListener shareButtonListener = new OnClickListener()   
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {        
        vibrate();
        PaintView.shareImage(ActivtyA.this);
      };
   };
```

### Logcat:

```
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at com.pearmak.drawing.ActivityA.onCreate(ActivityA.java:102)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
02-02 16:01:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9809):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Show error please. Im guessing you havent recorded the activity in th e android manifest file

Comment: yes, do print the error message.

Comment: thanks for your prmopt reply!! the code is not executable yet and hence no logcat yet. It is the code-writing panel where the error is underlined

Comment: @pearmak : use `Your_Current_Activity_Name.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share drawing"));` instead of `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share drawing"));` for starting Activity

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K : still not works =(

Comment: @pearmak : where u are calling shareImage() method ?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K : oh, calling this method from another Activity (Activity A), as this Activity - PaintView is the screen for the Painting Main View

Comment: @pearmak : where is ActivityA.java:102 line?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: thanks for your keen on support!! the error line now all gone (both in ActivityA and PaintView Activity), yet when trying to run it crashed...posted Logcat and revision of the codes for both activities...hope you can try help...really many thanks!

Comment: line 102 is       shareBtn.setOnClickListener(shareButtonListener);

Comment: @pearmak : make sure savedFilePath is not null ?

Comment: oh!! it is a stupid error for that!! i have not yet declared the sharebutton....and now it works!!!

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: really many thanks for your help and patience indeed!!! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to pass Activity Context to Non Activity class by using constructor or by changing method to parametrized method as :

```
public class PaintView extends View 
{      
  Context context_new;
  public PaintView(Context context){
    this.context_new=context;
  }
   //.. your code here
   public void shareImage(Context context)
   {

     context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share drawing"));
     //OR
     //context_new.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share drawing"));
      Toast.makeText(context, 
          "Please save the image first...",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

      //OR
         // Toast.makeText(context_new, 
         // "Please save the image first...",
         //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

   }

}
```

and call shareImage method from Activity as :

```
PaintView paintview=new PaintView(Your_Current_Activity.this);
paintview.shareImage(Your_Current_Activity.this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to call `startActivity()` from a class that's not your `Activity` class. The `startActivity()` method belongs to the `Context` class, so you either need to call it from your `Activity` (which extends `Context`) or pass an instance of `Context` to this class and use the `context.startActivity()` call. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as `startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share drawing"));`

Comment: i think  startActivityForResult take to param first intent and second request code